# ForEach loop data insert into two database table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop, foreach

```
$imagesarray[]=explode('&',$data[5]);
            $imag_temp  =   0;
            foreach($imagesarray as $image){
                if($imag_temp == 0 )
                {
                    $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET image = 'media/" . $image[0] . "' WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
                }else{
                    foreach($image as $img){
                            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_image SET image = 'media/" . $img . "' , product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
                    }
                }
                $imag_temp++;               

            }

This is my $data[5]=Arizona Diamondbacks.png&arizona-cardinals.png&Atlanta Braves.jpg&...&...&...n number can have..
```

I have writend query for each for where..in that every first image should insert to one table and remaining all other images should insert to another table..now for every loop first image conidering as first /.

Comment: are you using `codeigniter `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need $imagesarray[] if this is for a single product.

Say

```
 $data[5] = "Arizona Diamondbacks.png&arizona-cardinals.png&Atlanta Braves.jpg";
 $imagesarray = explode('&',$data[5]);
```

Will create an array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Arizona Diamondbacks.png
    [1] => arizona-cardinals.png
    [2] => Atlanta Braves.jpg
)
```

Then using single variable assign the query to perform

```
foreach($imagesarray as $key => $image){

    if($key == 0 )
    {
        $query = "UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET image = 'media/" . $image . "' WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'";
    } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_image SET image = 'media/" . $image . "' , product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'";
    }
    $this->db->query($query); 
}
```

Comment: i want first image Array
(
    [0] => Arizona Diamondbacks.png ;) this would insert/update in one table for every loop remainig will go to another table

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want, but you have some basic errors. You should learn more about php and sql before try to code something.

- You don't need to add `[]` to the `$imagesarray` when explode the `$data[5]`
- In the `foreach` loop the `$image` variable is a string, not an array
- your `INSERT` query is incorrect, you should take a look to the documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

Your code should be something like this

```
$imagesarray = explode('&',$data[5]);
$imag_temp = 0;
foreach($imagesarray as $image){
    if($imag_temp == 0 )
    {
        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "product SET image = 'media/$image' WHERE product_id = '$product_id'");
    }else{
        foreach($image as $img){
                $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "product_image (image, product_id) VALUES ('media/$image', '$product_id')");
        }
    }
    $imag_temp++;               

}
```

Make some research to learn how sql and php work, and make some debug because your code can have more bugs

Answer (score 0):

what is the error you are getting.. your insert query is not correct. 
and other thing you have to notice is what type of array you are getting ...

You can edit this as required

this code is working you can modify with your insert and update query..

```
<?php 
$data[5]='Arizona Diamondbacks.png&arizona-cardinals.png&Atlanta Braves.jpg';

$imagesarray[]=explode('&',$data[5]);

foreach ($imagesarray[0] as $key => $value) {
    if($key==0){
        echo "hello"; // here is your update query 
    }
    else{
        echo "sorry"; // here is your insert query 
    }

}
```